# Clarification on "Calculate e^x without inbuilt functions in Java"

Tags: java, loops, iteration

The question was basically to calculate e^x without inbuilt functions in Java.
The sequence to code was e^x = 1+x+x2/2!+x3/3!+x4/4!+ ...

Here was my attempt at the question:

```
public static void myexp(double x, double i){
    double j = 1.0;
    double sum = x;
    while (j <= i){
        j = j + 1;
        sum = sum + (sum * (x / (j)));
        System.out.println(sum + 1 + x);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x = 1;
    double i = 5.0;
    myexp(x, i);
}
```

Now it wasn't working, and eventually I gave in and looked up what a model answer should look like (I know, I know). Here is what it is (in the style of my code):

```
public static void myexp(double x, double i){
    double j = 1.0;
    double sum = x;
    double result = 1.0;
    while (j <= i){
        j = j + 1;
        sum = sum * (x / (j));
        result = result + sum;
        System.out.println(result + x);
    }
}
```

Now the difference is the inclusion of the 'results' variable, which delineates the summation of the sequence. However, I thought I had incorporated that when I wrote 
"`sum = sum+(sum*(x/(j)));`". 
But the machine recognises one style and not the other. What gives?

Comment: It's not a style difference, you're just doing a fundamentally different calculation.

Comment: Yes: `sum` is not a sum anymore (`result` is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each iteration you are supposed to add to the total sum the term

```
sum * x / j
```

where `sum` is the term added in the previous iteration.

This means you must store the term added in the previous iteration in a separate variable.

If you use the same variable for the total `result` (which is supposed to be the sum of all the terms of all iterations) and for the term of the current iteration (`sum`), you get an entirely different result.

In other words

```
sum = sum + (sum * (x / (j)));
```

is not equivalent to

```
sum = sum * (x / (j));
result = result + sum;
```

since the value of `sum` depends on the previous value of `sum`, and therefore you can't eliminate that variable.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it now! I scratched my head trying to get to grips with what you were trying to say; eventually I took pen to paper and iterated what the algebra would look like for a few iterations in the two ways. And yes, they are different: the presence of the addition in my original method would compound into future iterations. I guess the lesson for me here is: split up your iterations! iterate over a term separately, and sum the terms separately. Two different routes calls for two different variables. Thanks! :)

Comment: (Note to self) Basically, it was initially hidden from me because I kept looking at the sequence strictly forwardly; in which case, yes, I can create a summative sequence by duplicating a current figure and adding one to an adjusted other. But what I missed was looking at the sequence backwards – and hence I missed how the additions would alter everything.